# Incrementing a row in a column from an empty column

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a question regarding incrementing a column in a table. So what I am trying to achieve is,

I am using a PHP program so that when user press a button then every row is inserted with DO_NO is incremented by 1 in every row insertion.

what I have for my SQL command is,

```
insert into delivery (packing_no, do_no) values ('PACKING1', ((select max(do_no) from delivery)+1))
```

packing_no is inserted based on a text input

the problem is,

1. When the table is empty, DO_NO is not updated. Means it keeps emptied.
2. I guess its not an efficient way to implement this kind of problem.

Anybody can suggest me a better way to solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: why not add an IF statement checking if the table is empty and setting do_no to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` condition and I do not see any other way to achieve this.

```
DECLARE varMax(INT)
SET varMax = (select max(do_no) from delivery);

insert into delivery (packing_no, do_no) 
values ('PACKING1', (CASE WHEN varMax IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE (varMax +1))
```

Or to simplify, you can check against the row count as well

```
SET varMax = (select count(do_no) from delivery);
```

Further simplifying it, as pointed in other answer, use `ISNULL`

```
insert into delivery (packing_no, do_no) 
values ('PACKING1', (select ISNULL(max(do_no),0)+1 from delivery))
```

Comment: 'insert into delivery (packing_no, do_no) 
values ('PACKING1', (select ISNULL(max(do_no),0)+1 from delivery))' I tried this but it shows an error : [Error] Execution (2: 29): ORA-00904: "ISNULL": invalid identifier

Comment: @user3736689 use `NVL()` instead of `ISNULL()`. Missed the oracle tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use ISNULL in this case

```
 insert into delivery (packing_no, do_no) values ('PACKING1', (select ISNULL(max(do_no),0)+1 from delivery))
```

What ISNULL is doing is to return 0 in case do_no is NULL or empty.

Comment: Oracle does not have an `ISNULL()` function. Use `NVL()` for Oracle instead. [Check this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp). Replace ISNULL in this query with NVL and you're golden!